# PropelORM with MySQL SPATIAL data type

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, propel, spatial-index

I'm using `PropelORM 1.6` and implementing some kind of GIS service for a project.
In database (*MySQL*), for coordinates, I'm using field type of POINT to store the coordinates for diverse items.

In `schema.xml` for building table model, I've set this (*POINT*) field to `VARCHAR(255)`, because AFAIK spatial data types are not yet supported.

Organizing select queries for this field is Ok using `Criteria::CUSTOM`, but when I want to update this field, using well known `GeomFromText` with Propel, I'm getting next error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1416 Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field in /var/www/.../propel/util/BasePeer.php on line 425

I'm setting field value using

> `$object->setGeo("GeomFromText( 'POINT(48.211055 16.383728)' )");`

I suppose that this string is treated like a string value by ORM and `GeomFromText` is not treated as a function like it should be.

Unfortunately there is no `Criteria::CUSTOM` for setting field value.

How can I update such fields with PropelORM ?

**UPDATE:** In `ZendFramework` there is `Zend_Db_Expr` for this kind of tasks, maybe there is something similar in PropelORM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've found for now is to use custom query and to update `GEOMETRY` field after record is saved.

Here is the function I'm using to extend functionality.

```
/**
 * Update spatial data field from numerical values of record
 * If record ID is not defined - all records will be updated from their own values
 *
 * @param int $record Record ID to update
 */
public function updateGEO($record = null) {

    $sql = 'UPDATE `'.TablePeer::TABLE_NAME.'` SET '.TablePeer::GEO.' = GeomFromText(CONCAT( \'POINT(\', '.TablePeer::LATITUDE.', \' \', '.TablePeer::LONGITUDE.', \')\' ))'.(!empty($record) ? ' WHERE '.TablePeer::ID.' = '.$record : null);

    return \Propel::getConnection(TablePeer::DATABASE_NAME)
            ->prepare($sql)
            ->execute();
}
```

Comment: I suppose that there is something to do with `Criteria::CUSTOM` in `doUpdate()`, but didn't have enough time to test it. I will post my research on this variant also.